# Struts2 library for confirmation email

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security

I just want to know if sending a "confirmation email" feature is provided out of the box for the struts2 framework. I've been using spring security for handling my login so something that plugs into that would really be helpful.

The "confirmation email" consists of a service which send emails with some kind of unique tokens and a service which receives those tokens and confirms your email is valid.

I also want to point out I was looking for an out of the box feature like this (aka plugin or whatever) as it seems a pretty standard way to confirm a mail is real. I did implement the feature myself in my app, but was half a day work I would have liked to spend on other stuff.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/home.html might help

Comment: didn't find what I was looking

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spring already, perhaps:

org.springframework.mail.MailSender

will work for you.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html

Comment: I was looking for something out of the box, like fiddle with a bean and have instant email confirmation